# Can i display multiple copies of a movieclip inside a array at once

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, flash, actionscript, movieclip

Is there a way to make the code below work properly? When I use this code it only shows one movieclip:

```
var tempHead:head001 = new head001();
var mcArr:Array = new Array( tempHead );

var firstHead:MovieClip = mcArr[0];
firstHead.y = 30;
addChild(firstHead);

var secondHead:MovieClip = mcArr[0];
secondHead.y = 180;
addChild(secondHead);
```

`

Answer (score 1):

You were just assigning a reference to the MovieClip. That'y, its not working.

First take instance of `head001` class using `new` operator as much you want and store it  to an array, then you can access very easily.

```
var tempHead: head001;
var mcArr: Array = new Array();

for (var i: uint = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    tempHead = new head001();
    addChild(tempHead);
    mcArr.push(tempHead);
    mcArr[i].y = mcArr[i].height * i;
}
```